# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

estoy tratando de mostrar elementos en react cuando un array tengo un `length` mayor a 0, el problema que me da es que cuando agrego un elemento a ese array, react me dice que la priedad length del array es indefinida no se por que

esto es lo que me tiene que mostrar al momento de que el length sea mayor que 0

```
{imagenes.length > 0 && (
  <Paper elevation={2}>

  </Paper>
)}
```

este es mi hook con la funcion para agregar un elemento

```
const [ imagenes, setImagenes ] = useState([])

const handleChangeFile = (e: any) => {
const { files } = e.target
for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  setImagenes((prev: any): any =>{
    prev.push(files[i])
  })
 }
}
```

no esta de mas agregar que los archivos que estoy agregando al array son de tipo File

quiero agregar, que al agregar mas de dos elemento s al array, este me dice que la propiedad push es undefined en la variable `prev` que es el array

Answer (score 0):

Los arreglos de tipo File no se recorren de la misma manera que los arrays y/u objectos tracionales, prueba con este método:

```
Array.from(field.photo.files).forEach(file => { ... });
```

Entonces en tu caso sería:

```
for (let i = 0; i < Array.from(files).length; i++) {
  setImagenes((prev: any): any =>{
    prev.push(files[i])
  })
}
```

Comment: De todos modos, el método que indicas no tiene relación alguna con dicho problema, el mismo se genera cuando se agrega un nuevo elemento al array